# PHP script to collect data from html form

Tags: php, forms

I'm having issues with a php script i wrote to collect form data from an html form, below is the code. I think is something simple that i'm missing, my php experience is limited.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Please try to be specific if you edit the code so i can see where the error was.

```
"\nComments:\n".$comments. ;
<?php
$error = "\n Please review the information you provided, there seems to be a problem" ;
$email1 = 'root@centos6.labform.localdomain' ;
$to = "$email1";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = "$firstname $lastname";
$headers = "From: $email \n";
$subject = 'Lab Systems Request Form';

// we now create the email

$message = array();
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ;
$extnumber = $_POST['extnumber'] ;
$department = $_POST['department'] ;
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$type = $_POST['type'] ;
$systems = $_POST['systems'] ;
$comments = $_POST['comments'] ;


$body = "We have received the following information from $name:\n\nHere are the details:\n"
"\nFirstName:\n".$firstname.
"\nLastName:\n".$lastname.
"\nExtNumber:\n".$extnumber.
"\nDepartment:\n".$department.
"\nEmail:\n".$email.
"\nFormFactor:\n".$type.
"\nSystemType:\n".$systems.
//$body ="We have received the following information from $name:\n\n";
//"Here are the details:\n " ;
//"FirstName: $firstname \n" ;
//"LastName: $lastname \n" ;
//"ExtNumber: $extnumber \n" ;
//"Department: $department \n" ;
//"Email: $email \n" ;
//"FormFactor: $type \n" ;
//"SystemType: $systems \n" ;
//"Comments: $comments \n" ;

// now we send the email and redirect to thankyou.html if all ok
$send = mail( $to,$from,$headers,$subject,$body );
//print "$to,$subject,$body,$headers";

if($send)
 {header( "Location: thankyou.html" );}
 else
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify directly
$email1 or $email2"; }

?>
```

Also, when i manage to print all the data for some reason it places a "1" in front of every line :-S and collects the data in reverse order
thanks very much!
stonith

hi,thanks for the replies. I have edited the code. i added your suggestions. the code runs ok, it redirects to thankyou.html but the email body is empty, if i add print at the begining of each : "\nFirstName:\n".$firstname. ....... then i can see the example data is collected but all i get is : Date: Thu, 19 Apr 2012 15:54:22 +0100 (IST) From: Apache  To: root@centos6.labform.localdomain Subject: root@centos6.labform.localdomain Lab Systems Request Form From: and no other data collected

here is the html form:
    http://dpaste.com/734277/
here is collection.php:
    http://dpaste.com/734276/

Comment: What error messages are you seeing or what is/isn't happening that you are expecting?

Comment: As Richard points out, this would fail with a syntax error. It is a good idea to check something at least _runs_ before posting!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments in the `mail()` function are in the wrong order. The from-adress should be in the headers. Look at [the manual for this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Antonio

You need to be more descriptive with what is going wrong along with all the code (We need to see the form), it sounds as thoght the script is being run however.

On top of what Lex said your $body variable has a . on the end that shouldn't be there:

```
$body = "We have received the following information from $name:\n\nHere are the details:\n"
"\nFirstName:\n".$firstname.
"\nLastName:\n".$lastname.
"\nExtNumber:\n".$extnumber.
"\nDepartment:\n".$department.
"\nEmail:\n".$email.
"\nFormFactor:\n".$type.
"\nSystemType:\n".$systems.
"\nComments:\n".$comments. ;
```

Should be:

```
$body = "We have received the following information from $name:\n\nHere are the      details:\n"
"\nFirstName:\n".$firstname.
"\nLastName:\n".$lastname.
"\nExtNumber:\n".$extnumber.
"\nDepartment:\n".$department.
"\nEmail:\n".$email.
"\nFormFactor:\n".$type.
"\nSystemType:\n".$systems.
"\nComments:\n".$comments ;
```

Comment: I'd say a better way to specify that string would be to have just a start and end delimiter (") and put in the line breaks literally. That gets rid of a great deal of open/close and concatenation.

Comment: halfer, is this whay you mean:

$body = "We have received the following information from ".$name.":\n\nHere are the details:\n\nFirstName:\n$firstname\nLastName:\n$lastname\nExtNumber:\n$extnumber\nDepartment:\n$department\nEmail:\n$email\nFormFactor:\n$type\nSystemType:\n$systems\nComments:\n$comments";

Comment: almost all working now, removed:
$message = $body
and changed $body = ...... to $message = ......
now all the form data is collected but '$from' shows blank

any suggestions?
thanks
Stonith

Comment: Does the $email variable have data?